# Difficulties starting out in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a complete beginner to android programming and wanted to try it out. I have created a project, explored the IDE and this is what's not working:

Whenever i drag and drop an item from the palette to the designer view the item shows up under the component tree, but does not show up in my designer view.

here is my interface and errors:[image: screenshot]

EDIT: I have now fixed the constraints and get [these new errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WE8F.png)

Comment: You should learn to use the xml to build your layouts. It can make it a lot easier to get what you want.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/ have a look at this.

Comment: EDIT: I have now fixed the constraints and get these new errors.

Answer (score 0):

While you have missing constraints the preview can't render. Fix your constraints and everything should show up in the preview.